# How to restrict user input to a couple values in a DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I need to come up with a way to restrict the user from entering anything other than `1` or `2` in a column in my dgv.  I have it so the user is restricted to entering a number, but I need further restrictions to meet the `FOREIGN KEY` constraints.

Any ideas?

Current Validation in place:

```
Private Sub dgvCategories_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) _
      Handles dgvCategories.EditingControlShowing

        CType(Me.dgvCategories.Columns(0), DataGridViewTextBoxColumn).MaxInputLength = 50
        CType(Me.dgvCategories.Columns(1), DataGridViewTextBoxColumn).MaxInputLength = 1
End Sub

Private Sub dgvCategories_DataError(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs) _
      Handles dgvCategories.DataError
        If StrComp(e.Exception.Message, "Input string was not in a correct format.") = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter either 1 (Expense) or 2 (Income) in the Transaction Type column.")
            'This will change the number back to original
            dgvCategories.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = " "
        End If
End Sub
```

Playing around with solutions:

```
Dim CurValue As Integer
Private Sub dgvCategories_CellEnter(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvCategories.CellEnter
        CurValue = dgvCategories.Rows.Item(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value
End Sub
Private Sub dgvCategories_CellEndEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvCategories.CellEndEdit
        Dim NewValue As Integer = dgvCategories.Rows.Item(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value
        If NewValue < 1 Or NewValue > 2 Then
            dgvCategories.Rows.Item(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = CurValue
        End If
End Sub
```

I get this error: `Conversion from string "Unassigned" to type 'Integer' is not valid.`

Which I'm assuming is from the `NULL` entries in the "New Row" of the datagridview.

Any guesses on how to modify this solution?

**EDIT:**  Thanks to Nocturnal, I changed my logic to this:

```
Private Function CleanInputNumber(ByVal str As String) As String
        Return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(str, "[03456789]", "1")
End Function

Private Sub xDataGridView_CellValidating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValidating

        If DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells("ColumnType").IsInEditMode Then

            Dim c As Control = DataGridView1.EditingControl

            Select Case DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name

                Case "ColumnType"
                    c.Text = CleanInputNumber(c.Text)

            End Select
        End If
End Sub
```

Works like a charm!

Comment: Post your code that enforces numeric

Comment: I recommend you to continue playing with `CellValueChanged` Event. This code: `If e.ColumnIndex >= 0 AndAlso e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
    dgvCategories(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value = "5"
End If`
would convert any input in the first column into "5" (always make sure that column/row are greater or equal than 0 when using this event). You can build as complex conditions as you wish on this method and change the given cell value or not.

Comment: (I replaced my previous suggestion; because I am writing code without testing; and CellValueChanged is more straightforward). Bear in mind that this suggestion (like the previous one) involves validation, for example, the user pressing enter. Dealing with what the user types while he is typing it is not so straightforward and might drive to a less reliable code.

Comment: Exactly for this purpose you have `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`. With this user can input only values you will give him.

Comment: @Fabio, That's a decent solution, but that method pulls duplicate values for the TypeID.  Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

many different ways to approach this .. i use RegEx

with this

```
Private Function CleanInputNumber(ByVal str As String) As String
    Return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(str, "[a-zA-Z\b\s-.]", "")
End Function
```

and this

```
Private Function CleanInputAlphabet(ByVal str As String) As String
    Return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(str, "[0-9\b\s-]", "")
End Function
```

you should figure it out

and this is the event i use

```
Private Sub xDataGridView_CellValidating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) Handles xDataGridView.CellValidating

    If xDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells("xColumn").IsInEditMode Then

        Dim c As Control = xDataGridView.EditingControl

        Select Case xDataGridView.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name

            Case "xColumn"
                c.Text = CleanInputNumber(c.Text)

                'Case "yColumn"
                '    c.Text = CleanInputAlphabet(c.Text)                

        End Select       
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This was perfect!  I updated my OP with what I changed my code to.  Thanks!