# e.SuppressKeyPress Not Working

Tags: vb.net, validation, datagridview

In a VB.NET project (.NET 4.0) I need to restrict user entries into a DataGridView's cells to certain characters.

In the EditingControlShowing event I'm getting the column index and adding a handler depending on what column type it is (to restrict date, numbers, etc).

Here's my EditingControlShowing event:

```
Private Sub dgvEmployees_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles dgvEmployees.EditingControlShowing
    Dim index As Integer = dgvEmployees.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex

    RemoveHandler e.Control.KeyDown, AddressOf NumberOnlyCells_KeyDown
    RemoveHandler e.Control.KeyDown, AddressOf DateCells_KeyDown
    RemoveHandler e.Control.KeyDown, AddressOf YesNoCells_KeyDown
    RemoveHandler e.Control.KeyDown, AddressOf DecimalValueCells_KeyDown

    If index = 3 Then
        ' Dept column
        AddHandler e.Control.KeyDown, AddressOf NumberOnlyCells_KeyDown
    ElseIf index = 4 OrElse index = 5 OrElse index = 6 Then
        ' Date columns
        AddHandler e.Control.KeyDown, AddressOf DateCells_KeyDown
    ElseIf index = 7 OrElse index = 8 Then
        ' Y/N columns
        AddHandler e.Control.KeyDown, AddressOf YesNoCells_KeyDown
    ElseIf index = 12 OrElse index = 13 Then
        ' Goals columns
        AddHandler e.Control.KeyDown, AddressOf DecimalValueCells_KeyDown
    End If

End Sub
```

I added the RemoveHandler lines because at first I noticed that all of my KeyDown Subs were being fired. I also made sure that the indexes were calling the correct Sub

And here's one of my KeyDown subs

```
Private Sub YesNoCells_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)
    'Console.WriteLine("e.KeyValue: " & e.KeyValue)

    ' Allow only y, n, delete and backspace keys
    If e.KeyValue <> 8 AndAlso
        e.KeyValue <> 46 AndAlso
        e.KeyValue <> 78 AndAlso
        e.KeyValue <> 89 Then

        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
    End If

End Sub
```

The rest are similar depending on the keys I need to supress and I also ensured in the Immediate Window that my If/Then logic is correctly evaluating.

Stepping through the process, the `e.SupressKeyPress = True` lines are getting hit when an invalid character is pressed, but the character is shown in the DGV cell anyway. For instance, if I press the number 5 (e.KeyValue = 53) in one of the Y/N columns, the above Sub is called and the e.SuppressKeyPress = True line is hit, but the 5 shows in the cell anyway.

I also added `e.Handled = True` to the KeyDown Sub, but that didn't have any effect.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

I found that using "KeyPress" instead will work:

EditingControlShowing event:

```
AddHandler e.Control.KeyPress, AddressOf YesNoCells_KeyDown
```

And the handling Sub:

```
Private Sub YesNoCells_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs)
    Console.WriteLine("e.KeyValue: " & e.KeyChar)

    If e.KeyChar.ToString().ToUpper() <> "Y" AndAlso
        e.KeyChar.ToString().ToUpper() <> "N" Then

        e.Handled = True
    End If

End Sub
```

This works, **but** as far as I can tell, I'll have to have a single line for each character I want to allow, plus after a quick search I can't find KeyChar values for things like Backspace or Del.

I'm not sure that's the best way to go.

Any suggestions?

Comment: @ LarsTech I just tried it and got the same result - it evaluates to true and the SupressKeyPress line is hit, but the character still shows in the grid.

Comment: OK, I went ahead and tried your code.  No repro.  I press the number 5 and it does not show up in the grid.

Comment: Okay, then something else must be going on - any idea how I can figure out what? I've been working on this issue for two hours and I'm stumped.

Comment: I don't think your `RemoveHandler` lines are going to do what you expect them to do.  If `Control` is the control that is_currently_ being edited then it will try to remove it from that control instead of the previous one that had the handler attached.  You could end up with multiple sets of controls still bound to your handler.  To fix your input problem you may also need to set `e.handled` to true in addition to suppressing the key.

Comment: @LarsTech I forgot to mention that I did try e.Handled, I added that to my Question. I also updated with a test on using the KeyPress event with mixed results...

Comment: you can also use regex here is an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21999570/how-to-restrict-user-input-to-a-couple-values-in-a-datagridview/22002681#22002681

Answer (score 0):

just put in keypress eventandler

Private Sub MDIParent1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress

**e.Handled = True**

```
End Sub
```

it works for me