# Datagridview Dataerror not capturing user input in datetime column

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a column in a databound `datagridview` with datatype `datetime`, which displays just the time.  If the user enters a time, the date and time for the cell is set in the `.CellValueChanged` event with the date coming from another column.
It works as expected if the user enters the time in the correct format.

So if the user enters "8:00", this is parsed as a time correctly. The date and time is updated and the cell displays "8:00"

If the user enters 8 then the `dataerror` event fires.

I want to get the user input, and convert it into a time.  However in the example below, the variable `numberinput` is `NULL`, not what the user has entered at all.

Can I capture what the user has entered?

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_DataError(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.DataError
    'handle incorrect date formats

    e.ThrowException = False

    Dim numberinput As Single
    numberinput = Val(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value)
    Select Case True
        Case Val(numberinput) = 0
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = DBNull.Value
        Case numberinput = Int(numberinput)
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = RelevantDate.AddHours(numberinput)
    End Select

    e.Cancel = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Google on how to override DGV column. You need to create a custom column for your grid in which you can accept any data and parse it before submitting to datasource. This is all you need to do is override parsing of the text box on data entry to whatever you like using `timespan`, for example

Answer (score 0):

I think I was barking up the wrong tree looking at .DataError

This works:

```
    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValidating(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValidating
    If DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(e.ColumnIndex).IsInEditMode Then

        Dim c As Control = DataGridView1.EditingControl

        If DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).ValueType = Type.GetType("System.DateTime") Then
            c.Text = CleanInputDate(c.Text)
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

lifted pretty much straight from this question:
[How to restrict user input to a couple values in a DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21999570/how-to-restrict-user-input-to-a-couple-values-in-a-datagridview?rq=1)